# Proving that the expected value of the sup equals infinity

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I would like some help proving the following result. Thanks for any help in advance.

> Let $(x_{n})$, $n\geq 1$ be a sequence of random variables and suppose that
>
> (1) for all 0 < M <$\infty$,
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} |x_{k}| \geq M) = 1$$
>
> Prove that $E(\sup_{n \geq 1}|x_{n}|) = \infty$

Edit 1: I originally had the limit as X goes to infinity. I corrected this so that n goes to infinity.

Edit 2: I am not sure why this has been marked as off-topic.

Edit 3: So far, I have used the Markov Inequality to conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty} E(max_{1 \leq k \leq n} |x_{k}|) = \infty$. I don't see how iI can jump from this step to concluding that the $E(\sup_{n \geq 1}|x_{n}|) = \infty$

Edit 4: Disregard Edit 3 above. I can simply apply the Lebesgue Monotone Convergence Theorem in the final step.

Comment: Not sure if helpful but 1. suppose on the contrary that $E[\sup] < \infty$. Then $\sup < \infty$. 2. We have $P(\liminf A_n) = \liminf P(A_n) = \limsup P(A_n) = P(\limsup A_n) = 1 \to P(\limsup A_n^C) = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_n=\max_{i\leq k\leq n}|X_k|$ for notational simplicity. Notice that for all $n$, $S_n\leq \sup_{n\geq1} |X_n|$ and also, $S_n$ is increasing in $n$. The latter property suggests that $E(S_n)$ is also increasing in $n$ showing $\lim_n E(S_n)$ also exists..

Thus we have the inequality $\sup_{n\geq1} |X_n|\geq S_n$ for every $n$ implying $E(\sup_{n\geq1}|X_n|)\geq E(S_n)$ for all $n$.

Now $E(S_n)=\int_0^\infty P(S_n>t)dt=\int_0^1 P(S_n>t)dt+\int_1^\infty P(S_n>t)dt\geq \int_1^\infty P(S_n>t)dt$

Thus, $\lim_n E(S_n)\geq \liminf_n \int_1^\infty P(S_n>t)dt\geq \int_1^\infty \liminf_n P(S_n>t)dt=\int_1^\infty 1dt=\infty$

Notice that in the above, the inequality obtained on interchanging liminf and integral was due to Fatou's lemma.

Hence $E(\sup_{n\geq1}|X_n|)\geq \lim_n E(S_n)=\infty$ which gives the answer.

Comment: I don't think that you can conclude that the expected value of the sup(|X|) is greater than or equal to the limit of the expected value of the max (|x|). I would need to see more detail at the end.

Comment: Actually, I was making this into a bigger problem than I needed to. Anyway, I will give you credit for your answer.

Comment: Yes I can conclude that since $\sup_n |X_n|$ is independent of $n$.

Comment: By the way, the problem says too much. The answer can be obtained in several ways: MCT, DCT, Fatou: whichever you like. And the answer doesn't depend half on what the question says. Curious as to where you got the question.